# GetCustomAttributes getting me wrong attribute

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I have a curious situation that I would like to understand better so that I can fix elegantly.

I have an enum with description attributes on each of the values as follow :

```cs
public enum LambdaPackageError : int
{
   __packageOffset = 100,

   // base errors
   __base_offset = __packageOffset,
   [Description("Base error 0")]
   BaseError0 = __base_offset,
   [Description("Base error 1")]
   BaseError1 = __base_offset + 1,
   [Description("Base error 2")]
   BaseError2 = __base_offset + 2,


   // extended errors
   __extended_offset = __packageOffset + 10,
   [Description("Extended error 0")]
   ExtendedError0 = __extended_offset,
   [Description("Extended error 1")]
   ExtendedError1 = __extended_offset+ 1
}
```

And now this is the snippet that would get the description attached to the enum entry :

```cs
public string GetDescriptionAttribute<T>(T value)
{
    var attr = typeof(T)
               .GetField(value.ToString())
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
               .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
               .FirstOrDefault();

    return attr?.Description;
}
```

Nothing crazy here

```cs
GetDescriptionAttribute<LambdaPackageError>(LambdaPackageError.BaseError2);      // ==> Returns attribute, OK
GetDescriptionAttribute<LambdaPackageError>(LambdaPackageError.ExtendedError1);  // ==> Returns attribute, OK
GetDescriptionAttribute<LambdaPackageError>(LambdaPackageError.__packageOffset); // ==> Returns nothing, OK
```

However, this is the curiousity :

```cs
GetDescriptionAttribute<LambdaPackageError>(LambdaPackageError.BaseError0);      // ==> Returns nothing. Wait .. what ?
```

When I check what the above state does, it actually resolves it to `LambdaPackageError.__base_offset` rather than `LambdaPackageError.BaseError0`.

The obvious is that they have the same value `= 100` behind the scene, but this is not what I asked the method to give me.

Any ideas on how to get the proper description attribute in this case ( Besides changing the intrinsic enum value ) ? I don't see any method overloads that would help me in that scope..

Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: Please post actual code, the `GetAttribute` snippet is not real code.

Comment: @DavidG, Actual code does more things that is not in the scope of this question, so I posted pseudo code for simplication purpose.

Comment: That doesn't matter, you need to give us a [mre]

Comment: Note that your update is *still* not valid code. What is `T`? What is `value`? I know we can infer it, but many people will take your code and paste it into Visual Studio to run it, and when it has errors, they will give up immediately. If you want help, give people a question that has all of the relevant information.

Comment: So basically you're asking if it's possible that `GetDescriptionAttribute` for value `100` returns both `null` and `"Base error 0"`?

Comment: @DavidG you're right sorry. I indeed gave you an half baked snippet :S Fixed it.

Comment: @Knoop, I wanted to understand the reasoning behind this logic. That is , why is `typeof(T).GetField(value.ToString())` asks me which field by NAME, but then returns me the field by value.

Comment: I would advise you to store the result of `ToString()` in a variable and debug it, that will make it clear why this isn't working. And also why this will never work. All `ToString()` receives is the value `100` and it tries it's best to find a corresponding name.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `enum`s are really just glorified integers. So when you pass in `LambdaPackageError.BaseError0`, that resolves to 100 which becomes `LambdaPackageError.__packageOffset` or `LambdaPackageError.__base_offset` (I'm not sure what the rules are for which one is actually chosen)

It looks like you are using the offsets as a base values to start your enum values at but I suspect you don't use that elsewhere in code. So instead I would suggest moving that value out as a private `const` values, for example:

```
private const int __packageOffset = 100;
private const int __base_offset = __packageOffset;
private const int __extended_offset = __packageOffset + 10;

public enum LambdaPackageError : int
{
    [Description("Base error 0")]
    BaseError0 = __base_offset,
    [Description("Base error 1")]
    BaseError1 = __base_offset + 1,
    [Description("Base error 2")]
    BaseError2 = __base_offset + 2,

    // extended errors
    [Description("Extended error 0")]
    ExtendedError0 = __extended_offset,
    [Description("Extended error 1")]
    ExtendedError1 = __extended_offset + 1
}
```

Comment: I actually really like your answer. That was a silly solution which is the one I prefer ! (I try to abide by the KISS principle).

Comment: However, this answers half the question :  why is `typeof(T).GetField(value.ToString())` asks me what field by NAME, but then returns me the field by value ? This strikes me as a little incoherent and I wanted to understand why. I understand you when you talk about glorified integers but I wasn't expecting the reflection to return me the unexpected information..